# `Unexpected element ‘\’ in format string` in code written for MS Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77

I am trying to compile a old Fortran application, original written for Microsoft Fortran (v3.3 1985, F77) using GNU Fortran.

> The bigger question: What is the easiest way to compile a  Microsoft Fortran DOS application compiling to a binary for Windows?

I get a large number of errors if I try to compile this code using `f77`, mainly in printing output (to screen/file). How can I fix?

```
   110 FORMAT(/,10X,'    Enter action : '\)
                                         1
Error: Unexpected element ‘\’ in format string at (1)
APP1.FOR:107:20:

   120 WRITE(*,'(1X,2A\)')CH,'[2J'
                    1
Error: Unexpected element ‘\’ in format string at (1)
APP1.FOR:121:44:
```

What is the syntax of WRITE?

```
   120 WRITE(*,100)
                 1
Error: FORMAT label 100 at (1) not defined
```

Comment: The `\ ` in a format string is a non-standard extension supported by some compilers that suppresses a newline after the output (so reading input happens on the same line as the prompt).   There is no equivalent in standard Fortran 77.    The syntax `WRITE(*,100)` is valid, but for it to work, there needs to be a format statement with label `100` in the same subprogram (akin to the format `110` you have shown).   The compiler is telling you there is no such format statement in that sub-program.

Comment: The main line from my - now moved to the other question - answer: *"The backslash is not valid in Fortran 77 FORMAT statements. Gfortran will not compile it, unless you fix the code."*

Comment: *"What is the easiest way to compile a Microsoft Fortran DOS application compiling to a binary for Windows?"* That is quite a different question, for a different post, but **very likely too broad**. There are simply too many issues depending on what kind of non-standard problems you are currently hitting. The code you show can probably be compiled with Intel Fortran (costs money).